# Azure DevOps hosted in Australia only

Tags: azure, devops

My work place has a software integration with an Australian government agency, that has a specific requirement that our software and any version of it, must reside wholly geographically within Australia.

We currently use Azure DevOps previously known as TFS (Team Foundation Services) and I'm fairly certain it's hosted in the States which violates their terms.  And I'd assume so too is GitHub. We only a 4 man team and we're not doing pipelines or anything else, just version control and so far it's been free.  I'd prefer to stick with DevOps so I don't have to re-train the old dudes, who happen to be the business owners.

Is it possible to use DevOps Services or Server but specifically **hosted in** and perhaps also **geo-locked** for Australia only?

Comment: I wonder if the requirement is pointless security theatre anyway. If you move the data to Australia, as the answer below suggestions, I expect Microsoft staff in the US could still read or write it if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/data-location?view=azure-devops), you can choose to have your Azure DevOps instance and data located in Australia (Australia is one of the supported geographies). You can specify the region while creating your organization or by raising a support ticket later on.

If this does not work for you, you can always opt to host Azure DevOps on-premise using Azure DevOps Server. You can learn more about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/server/.

Comment: Good to know I wasn't going crazy. All roads lead me to their Virtual Support Agent, which then promptly tells us we don't have a DevOps organisation - when in fact we do.